# How to avoid ajax timeouts on lift?

Tags: timeout, lift, ajaxform

I'm using ajax+comet to build an iterative form. When it is submited, an output file is downloaded.

```
def render = ajaxForm(bind("form",/*...*/
  "submit" -> ajaxSubmit("Calculate",result _)))++hidden(result _)

private def result : JsCmd = {
  /* Some really time-consuming calculations */
  JsCmds.RedirectTo("/result/"+uniqueId)
}
```

It works most cases. Although, as there are some really long-lasting calculations, I'm getting the "the server could not respond" message (sometimes it just doesn't redirect with no error message).

I tried to reconfigure the ajax timeout:

```
LiftRules.ajaxPostTimeout = Int.MaxValue
```

But even than It's still not redirecting.

I could also decouple the redirect part from the calculations and do something like:

```
{val func = ajaxInvoke({() => JsCmds.RedirectTo("/result/"+uniqueId)})._2.cmd
Script(OnLoad(func))}
```

But I need to replace OnLoad for something that works on reRender and not only on full page reload. Or maybe to force somehow my page to reload without client iteraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiftRules
var ajaxPostTimeout = 5000 //m

Comment: Sorry, 'm' is milliseconds or minutes?

Comment: Was there ever something in minutes in programming and does 5000 minutes make any sense??? It's milliseconds